# How can I make the auto-complete feature in emacs match long perl variables?

Tags: perl, emacs, autocomplete

The best auto-complete can do is match word characters. For example: auto-complete will only match $longvariablename in a previously used variable, $longvariablename[$i]{'key'}. I would like to configure auto-complete, or any other emacs el file to match the entire variable.

As a last resort, I'm going to have to learn lisp #shudder#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not 100% clear which you want...  you want it to complete all the way to the closing } ?

Answer (score 3):

You can customize [hippie expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand).

For example the following customization expands all strings until a space or a semicolon.

```
(defun try-expand-perl-extended-var (old)
  (let ((old-fun (symbol-function 'he-dabbrev-search)))
    (fset 'he-dabbrev-search (symbol-function 'perl-extended-var-search))
    (unwind-protect
        (try-expand-dabbrev old)
      (fset 'he-dabbrev-search old-fun))))


(defun perl-extended-var-search (pattern &optional reverse limit)
  (let ((result ())
    (regpat (concat (regexp-quote pattern) "[^ ;]+")))
    (while (and (not result)
        (if reverse
             (re-search-backward regpat limit t)
             (re-search-forward regpat limit t)))
      (setq result (buffer-substring-no-properties (save-excursion
                                                     (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                                                     (skip-syntax-backward "w_")
                                                     (point))
                           (match-end 0)))
      (if (he-string-member result he-tried-table t)
      (setq result nil)))     ; ignore if bad prefix or already in table
    result))
```

Don't forget to include your custom function into `make-hippie-expand-function` list

```
(global-set-key [(meta f5)] (make-hippie-expand-function
                               '(try-expand-perl-extended-var
                                 try-expand-dabbrev-visible
                                 try-expand-dabbrev
                                 try-expand-dabbrev-all-buffers) t))
```